# error while refreshing power bi repport:ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][Hardy] (115) Connection failed with error: SSL_read: error code: 0

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, powerbi, azure-databricks

hello everyone i'm facing this errors many times while i'm trying to refresh my power bi repport in power bi services **"ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][Hardy] (115) Connection failed with error: SSL_read: error code: 0 "** the data source is azure databricks and i'm using the spark connector.
I have already connected to databricks using power bi desktop without any problems, the problem is after i have published my repport on power bi services and i scheduled the refresh of my data, often the data refresh without any problem often it gives me the  error above .

Answer (score 0):

As enough information is not provided with this question, it is difficult to find the exact cause of the error.

You can also refer this MSFT Q&A [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/131106/jdbcodbc-connection-to-azure-dataricks-fails.html) by pradeepcheekatla

You can use [Databricks Partner Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/partner-connect/) to connect a cluster with Power BI Desktop.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/power-bi#---connect-with-power-bi-desktop-by-using-partner-connect

Comment: I have already connected to databricks using power bi desktop without any problems, the problem is after i have published my repport on power bi services and i scheduled  the refresh of my data often the data refresh without any problem often it gives me that error that i mentioned in the question.